# Project gets unloaded when opening with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to open a solution using Visual studio 2019 and visual studio 2017. All the projects in the solution are loading except for one. When trying to load the unloaded project i get an error in the output window as

> TakstMVC.csproj : error  : The imported project
> "....build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets" was not found. Confirm
> that the expression in the Import declaration
> "TakstMVC\.....build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets" is correct,
> and that the file exists on disk.  TakstMVC\FluentMigrator.targets

When i tried to open using VS 2017 i saw a migration report which said

> TakstMVC.csproj: The application which this project type is based on
> was not found. Please try this link for further information:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47

Part of the .csproj of the project is as below:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{A4354F5C-ECF5-4621-AA9E-B91FE543F096}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>TakstMVC</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>TakstMVC</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>4.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <MvcProjectUpgradeChecked>true</MvcProjectUpgradeChecked>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I have the following installed in my computer

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1 SDK
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.1 SDK Targeting Pack (ENU)
- Microsoft .NET Core 3.1.1 - Windowsserver hosting
- Microsoft .NET Core SDK 3.1.101 (x64)
- Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.2.207 (x64)
- Microsoft .NET Core Runtime - 3.1.1
- Microsoft .NET Core Runtime - 2.2.8

I tried to install dotnetfx35.exe but it doesnt even run when executed (not even a message or error).
The windows feature are as below:
[image]

How can I identify the target framework of the project and load it in visual studio successfully ? appreciate some advise on this.

Comment: Going through the Porject guid types i notied they belong to MVC 4, MVC 5 and C#. Is it not possible to launch or identify MVC projects in Visual studio 2017. I installed ASP.NET 4 with no luck.

Comment: Hi, any update about the issue?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT the files are available under the "packages" folder in the solution. But it is not recognized by visual studio. Also i noticed when trying to build the remaining projects all the references to libraries in the package folder are not recognized. (For an example the dlls for AutoMapper, EntityFramework, NewtonSoft.Json, NUnitTestAdapter are not recognized in the solution). I get build errors saying all those dll's could not be found.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT in the .csproject the references as as : 
  
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    
<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
|
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT and the references to the packages are as 
<HintPath>..\..\packages\AutoMapper.3.3.0\lib\net40\AutoMapper.Net4.dll</HintPath>
<HintPath>..\..\packages\Cassette.Aspnet.2.4.2\lib\net40\Cassette.Aspnet.dll</HintPath>
<HintPath>..\..\packages\Common.Logging.2.1.2\lib\net40\Common.Logging.dll</HintPath>
<HintPath>..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.0.2\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>

Comment: I think the issue is that the hintpath is incorrect due to some reasons. When your `hintpath` is not point to the dlls under packages folder, it will turn out the error of not found. So my suggestion is to reinstall them. Please check my update answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clear that you did not import the `MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets` correctly on your local area. The reason is that you did not install `MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets` on your PC or the import path from `csproj` file is incorrect.

You should [check this document](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks#msbuild-community-tasks) to install the right target.

**First**, remove xml node under `csproj` file like these:

```
 <Import Project="..\build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets" Condition="Exists('..\build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets')" />


 <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\build\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.targets'))" />
  </Target>
```

**Second**, [install the msi file](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/releases).

then, add these under the csproj file:

```
<Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>
```

**Besides**, you could also use nuget function. First, uninstall the nuget package if you have a old version on the project. Then, use the first suggestion to remove any previous `import projects="xxx\MSBuildTasks.targets"`. After that, install the [MSBuildTasks nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuildTasks). That is the same.

**Update**

Try to You should change `..\..\` to `..\`. Use the right path.

**Or** use this command under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

```
update-package -reinstall
```

## **Answer from the Customer**

embarrassingly enough the whole issue was with the solution path where my solution was located in my local computer. I had a long path including a folder having two words as well. After trying everything else I moved the solution folder to C:\temp folder and the issue was no longer there. The error showed in VS was quite misleading. What a waist of time. Thank you for your efforts !

Comment: the files are available under the "packages" folder in the solution. But it is not recognized by visual studio. Also i noticed when trying to build the remaining projects all the references to libraries in the package folder are not recognized. (For an example the dlls for AutoMapper, EntityFramework, NewtonSoft.Json, NUnitTestAdapter are not recognized in the solution). I get build errors saying all those dll's could not be found.

Comment: embarrassingly enough the whole issue was with the solution path where my solution was located in my local computer. I had a long path including a folder having two words as well. After trying everything else I moved the solution foler to C:\temp folder and the issue was no longer there. The error showed in VS was quite misleading. What a waist of time. Thank you for your efforts !

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `*.vcxproj.user` file under the project, then right-click the project -> Reload the project (you will find that the `*.vcxproj.user` file will be generated again)